# Exporting SQL Server to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, google-cloud-sql

Anyone know how to export data to Google cloud SQL from a SQL Server database?

The google documentation only gives an example for mySQL using mysqldump. I have looked for a similar program for SQL Server and have not found one.

Any ideas?